# Refer a class connected to one project to another project java

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, import, project

I have two projects ProjectA and ProjectB,ProjectA is maven project which has database connection.Project B is non maven project,I need to import Project A into projectB and access those classes and retrive the content from db.

Comment: you just want to import a maven project into a simple java project? or you wana create a dependency? or probably a reference?

Comment: I want to use ProjectA as a kind of library to ProjectB so that to access all classes in ProjectB.